# showing the address of reference in C# (debugging WCF)

Tags: c#, wcf

I am debugging a WCF project with two-way communication. I have a callback with data that I store in an array the client, a WinForm, and use that for painting a control. As you can guess, the data disappears from writing in the array (really a list) to when I read the data.

For debugging I would like to see if I am **writing and reading the same object** so that the callback function isn't making some kind of copy and throw it away. For example I want to see the address of the this - pointer. How do I do that in VS2010 Exp?

**Edit**
Some code:

Field declaration:

```
    // the cards that the player have
    private List<Card> cards = new List<Card>();
```

callback handler:

```
    private void btnDraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Tuple<Card, string> update = PressedDraw(this);
        cards.Add(update.Item1);
        PaintCards();
    }
```

paint event:

```
   private void cardPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        Point fromCorner = new Point(20,12);
        int distance = 50;
        foreach (Card card in cards)
        {
            Point pos = fromCorner;
            pos.Offset(counter++ * distance, 0);
            Bitmap cardBitmap = 
                cardFaces[Convert.ToInt32(card.suit), 
                   Convert.ToInt32(card.rank)];

            Rectangle square = new Rectangle(pos, cardBitmap.Size);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(cardBitmap, square);
        }
```

When I debug I enter first in the callback handler and adds a `Card` in `cards`
`PaintCards()` calls `Invalidate` and the paint event is run. When in `cardPanel_Paint`, `cards.Count` is zero again.

Best regards.
Görgen

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the Watch/Locals/Autos windows, you can right-click on an object and select "Make Object ID" to give the object an identification number.  This number is effectively the same as a native object's address; it serves to identify.

The identity of an object is tracked across garbage collections and compactions, so across the lifetime of your application, you can tell if a certain object is the one you originally tagged.  This feature might help in your situation.

[This blog post](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/make-object-id.aspx) has a quick run-through of the feature.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it was the same object.

Comment: For those using Rider, we also have the option of giving an object an ID. Just right click an object in the debug watch window and click on the option "Make Object ID".

Answer (score 0):

The address of an object in c# can be changed by the garbage collector so you can not use that (and there is no straight forward method to do so).

But you can use [`Object.ReferenceEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx) to compare to objects to see if they are really the same.

**Edit:**
But it looks like you have messed things up something like this.

```
var a = new List<string> { "String1" };
var b = a;
a = new List<string> { "String 2" }; // really GetListFromWcf();
Console.WriteLine(b[0]);
```

this prints `String1`, not `String2`.

If you can not figure it out you need to post some code to show where thing get wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. The problem is that is supposedly the same object, just one F5 later, they are temporally separated. Any ideas?

Comment: @Gorgen, you need to show some code what you are doing. Can you post a minimalistic example that fails?

Comment: Yes I messed up, I recived two callbacks in reverse order, the first wrote and the second removed the data. Men tack för hjälpen i alla fall, när man sitter ensam hemma så är det alltid skönt att ha en virituell arbetskamrat